# Trying to copy and paste multiple files into a new directory

Tags: python

My excel sheet has a list of file names setup like this.
[List of file names in directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wXRY.png)

The ZINC.7482347382.pdbqt whatever is the file. The group/group50 stuff is the subdirectory it is in.

I would like to make a loop in Python that searches for each file, and copy it to a new folder so I do not have to find and copy the files myself. (I want to copy about 500 files or so for easier analysis.)

This is my current code.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

with open("Gabe_run1results.txt", "r") as my_file:
reader = csv.reader(my_file) # delimiter='\t')
my_list = list(reader)


myarray = np.asarray(my_list)
```

This code puts all the information into a list with the names listed in the picture, and then stores it an array so I can perform a loop with shutil.copy2 to find and copy the files.

Source is the parent file, and the str(myarray[i]) is the specific subdirectory.

```
l = 10 

import shutil

#shutil.copy2(source,destination)

for i in range (0,l):
    myarray[i]
    source = "/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/" + str(myarray[i])
    destination = "/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/blah"
    shutil.copy2(source,destination)
```

However, since the file names are stored as a string in the array, it returns the following error

Error: The source /Users/Gabriel/Desktop/["group/group50/ZINC7483743.pdbqt"] does not exist.

So basically I need to find a way to start over or just get the loop to read the array as group/group50/ZINC7483743.pdbqt and not as ["ZINC7483743.pdbqt"]

Any help I appreciate.

Comment: Your code doesn't add a `/` to `source`. Is that in the CSV entries? Or is this not your actual code? Or is the error actually telling you that `directoryspam` is missing rather than `directory/spam`?

Comment: Also, does the directory `directory` actually exist? What about any additional subdirectories inside `name of path`?

Comment: Finally, can you give us the actual exception (with traceback), not just a vague description of it?

Comment: @abarnert , I made the changes and hope that that clarifies the error and the issue.

Comment: OK, now that there’s enough info in the question, the problem is obvious. I’ll write an answer.

Comment: @abarnert, I tried the suggestion, and i got this error No such file or directory: '/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/groups/group559/ZINC67219131.pdbqt\n'

Answer (score 0):

You’re opening and reading a csv. The result is a list of rows—that is, a list of lists of columns.

Then you copy this into a numpy array—I’m not sure why you’re doing this, but it won’t change the shape: the only thing you can get out of this is a 2D array (or a 1D array whose values are lists, which is no better).

And then, you try to turn each one of these rows into a file name by using `str`. But all that does is get you the string representation of a 1D slice of a numpy array. And so your paths look like nonsense, with brackets and quotes in them. The error shows you the pathnames you’re trying to use:

```
Error: The source /Users/Gabriel/Desktop/["group/group50/ZINC7483743.pdbqt"] does not exist.
```

Surely you don’t have a file on your desktop named `[“group/group50/ZINC7483743.pdbqt”]`. The problem has nothing to do with needing to filter out the group50 stuff and add it back in later. You just need to use a path instead of a list of paths.

Since the path seems to always be the first column in your CSV (you only gave us one example, so I hope that one example is representative), you could fix it by doing this:

```
my_list = [row[0] for row in csv...]
```

instead of this:

```
my_list = list(csv...)
```

However, there’s a simpler solution. A CSV with one column isn’t really a CSV, it’s just a plain list of lines. So why are you even using the CSV module? Just open the file and then do `my_list = list(f)`. (Each line is a filename plus a newline, so you will need to `rstrip()` it to get the filename—but that's a lot simpler than parsing it as a CSV file when it isn't one.)

While we’re at it, why do you need the numpy array, or even the list? Why not just iterate the lines in the file directly?

Like this:

```
with open(‘file_with_one_relative_path_per_line) as f:
    for relpath in f:
        source = "/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/" + relpath.rstrip()
        destination = "/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/blah"
        shutil.copy2(source,destination)
```

Comment: I thought that putting it into an array would make it iterable, but I did not know you could iterate directory through the file itself.

Comment: I just tried the code you sent, and now it's giving me this error,

Comment: No such file or directory: '/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/groups/group559/ZINC67219131.pdbqt\n' . What does the /n even mean?

Comment: @BGP-python Oops, there’s a newline on the end of the filename. Use `relpath.rstrip()` instead of just `relpath`.

Comment: @BGP-python Lists are just as iterable as arrays—they’re the paradigm example of iterable, in fact. And anything you can do `list(it)` with has to be iterable; what `list(It)` does is (a slightly optimized version of) `for thing in it: self.append(thing)`.